# Laravel reset password link does not route to forgotten password form

Tags: php, laravel, function, api, routes

Please I am new to laravel; I have a Reset password link in my `login.blade.php` file but every other link works very well except the forgotten password link. Whenever it's clicked it seems like the page want to refresh and return to the same page.  I get 404 on validate.js as error on chrome.

I have tried to use Laravel documentation to rewrite the route in `web.php`. Tried to use this but it did not work so i commented it out:

```php
//Route::get('/forgot-password', function () { return view('auth.forget-password'); })-\>middleware('guest')-\>name('password.request');
```

Part of my `login.blade.php` file:

```php
<div class="form-group">
                                <button class="mt-4 btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="mb-3 text-center">
                                <small class="mb-2 text-center ">Forget your Password <a href="{{ route('password.request') }}" class="ml-1 link">Reset.</a> </small>
                                <small class="text-center ">Dont have an Account yet? <a href="{{route('register')}}" class="ml-1 link">Sign up.</a> </small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <hr>
                                <small class="text-center ">&copy; Copyright  {{date('Y')}} &nbsp; {{$settings->site_name}} &nbsp; All Rights Reserved.</small>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

This is my web.php, which has the route:

```php
Route::get('/forgot-password', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@forgotpassword')->name('password.request');
```

Tried to use this but it did not work so I commented it out:

```php
//Route::get('/forgot-password', function () { return view('auth.forget-password'); })->middleware('guest')->name('password.request');
```

This is my `forgot-password.blade.php`:

```php
@include('home.assetss')

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100 auth-page">
    <!-- ======= Loginup Section ======= -->
    <section class="auth">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center user-auth">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-10 col-xl-6 ">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        @if(Session::has('message'))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                            {{ Session::get('message') }}
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif

                        @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        
                        @endif   
                    </div>
                        
                    <div class="card ">
                        <h1 class="mt-3 text-center">Password Reset</h1>
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.email') }}" class="mt-5 card__form">
                            {{csrf_field()}} 
                            
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                                <small>Forgot your password? No problem. Just let us know your email address and we will email you a password reset link that will allow you to choose a new one.</small> <br>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" name ="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="mt-4 btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Email Password Reset Link</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3 text-center">
                                <small class="mb-2 text-center "> <a href="{{route('login')}}">Repeat Login.</a> </small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center">
                                <hr>
                                <small class="text-center ">&copy; Copyright  {{date('Y')}} &nbsp; {{$settings->site_name}} <br> All Rights Reserved.</small>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Tried to use this but it did not work so I commented it out:

```php
//Route::get('/forgot-password', function () { return view('auth.forget-password'); })->middleware('guest')->name('password.request');
```

I also tried making some changes on fortifyServiceProvider.php by adding requestPasswordResetLinkView but it did not work

```
   <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser;
use App\Actions\Fortify\ResetUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
use App\Models\Settings;

class FortifyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
        Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
        Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
        Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

        RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->email.$request->ip());
        });

        RateLimiter::for('two-factor', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->session()->get('login.id'));
        });
        
        Fortify::requestPasswordResetLinkView(function(){
            return view(view: 'auth.forgot-password');
        });

        Fortify::twoFactorChallengeView(function () {
            return view('auth.two-factor-challenge', [
                'title' => 'Two Factor Authentication',
                'settings' => Settings::where('id','1')->first(),
            ]);
        });

        Fortify::confirmPasswordView(function () {
            return view('auth.confirm-password', [
                'title' => 'Password Confirmation',
                'settings' => Settings::where('id','1')->first(),
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

this is my fortify.php

```
<?php

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Fortify\Features;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Fortify Guard
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which authentication guard Fortify will use while
    | authenticating users. This value should correspond with one of your
    | guards that is already present in your "auth" configuration file.
    |
    */

    'guard' => 'web',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Fortify Password Broker
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which password broker Fortify can use when a user
    | is resetting their password. This configured value should match one
    | of your password brokers setup in your "auth" configuration file.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => 'users',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Username / Email
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value defines which model attribute should be considered as your
    | application's "username" field. Typically, this might be the email
    | address of the users but you are free to change this value here.
    |
    | Out of the box, Fortify expects forgot password and reset password
    | requests to have a field named 'email'. If the application uses
    | another name for the field you may define it below as needed.
    |
    */

    'username' => 'email',

    'email' => 'email',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Home Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the path where users will get redirected during
    | authentication or password reset when the operations are successful
    | and the user is authenticated. You are free to change this value.
    |
    */

    'home' => RouteServiceProvider::HOME,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Fortify Routes Prefix / Subdomain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which prefix Fortify will assign to all the routes
    | that it registers with the application. If necessary, you may change
    | subdomain under which all of the Fortify routes will be available.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => '',

    'domain' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Fortify Routes Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which middleware Fortify will assign to the routes
    | that it registers with the application. If necessary, you may change
    | these middleware but typically this provided default is preferred.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => ['web'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Rate Limiting
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, Fortify will throttle logins to five requests per minute for
    | every email and IP address combination. However, if you would like to
    | specify a custom rate limiter to call then you may specify it here.
    |
    */

    'limiters' => [
        'login' => 'login',
        'two-factor' => 'two-factor',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register View Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify if the routes returning views should be disabled as
    | you may not need them when building your own application. This may be
    | especially true if you're writing a custom single-page application.
    |
    */

    'views' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Features
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some of the Fortify features are optional. You may disable the features
    | by removing them from this array. You're free to only remove some of
    | these features or you can even remove all of these if you need to.
    |
    */

    'features' => [
        Features::registration(),
        Features::resetPasswords(),
        Features::emailVerification(),
        Features::updateProfileInformation(),
        Features::updatePasswords(),
        Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
            'confirmPassword' => true,
        ]),
    ],

];
```

Answer (score 0):

lavarel "forgot password" defaults to this value "password.request"
put that in the href of your html:

```
{{ route('password.request') }}
```

that should work.